# En python 3 y pandas ¿Cómo resolver el error AttributeError: ("'module' object has no attribute 'infer_dtype'", 'occurred at index indice')?

Tags: python, pandas

Al leer un archivo CSV utilizando pandas y despues utilizar la sentencia:

```
prod.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

aparece el mensaje de error

```
AttributeError: ("'module' object has no attribute 'infer_dtype'", 'occurred at index indice')
```

Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

mi código es el siguiente:

```
 -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prod = pd.read_csv('datos_produccion.csv', index_col = 0, encoding = 'utf-8')
prod.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))
```

el archivo csv tiene el siguiente formato:

```
,indice,fecha,indice_planta,planta,indice_linea,linea,indice_supervisor,supervisor,indice_operador,operador,turno,plantilla,turno_horas,producto1,cajas_prod1,lbs_prod1,resto1,vel_producto1,tprod1
0,P3P3EA2CAROHUPET2172017,42917,P3,PLANTA 3,P3EA2,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 2,CARO,CARLOS ROSAS,HUPE,HUGO PEREZ,T2,11,8,producto 1,356,3204,,56,TERMINADO
1,P3P3EA6CAROALEST2172017,42917,P3,PLANTA 3,P3EA6,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 6,CARO,CARLOS ROSAS,ALES,ALEJANDRO ESPINOZA,T2,11,8,producto 1,1040,12480,,,TERMINADO
2,P3P3EA11ANSRMARST1172017,42917,P3,PLANTA 3,P3EA11,P3 EMB. AUTOMATICO 11,ANSR,ANTONIO SANTAROSA,MARS,MARCO ANTONIO RAMIREZ SALINAS,T1,12,9,producto 1,1206,14472,,50,TERMINADO
```

Comment: pon el CSV , object has no attribute 'infer_dtype'" parece que tenes mal puesto el nombre

Comment: Perdón, ¿podrías aclarar un poquito mas tu respuesta? ¿quieres que coloque el archivo csv?

Comment: Si claro , necesitamos mas informacion como yo puedo replicar el error si no tengo todos los datos ?

Comment: @Bruno Sosa Fast Tag . listo ya agregue el archivo

Comment: A  mí al menos me funciona perfectamente (python 3x)

Comment: creo que el problema esta al importar pandas. ya que no me reconoce el atributo pd.api.types.infer_dtype. estoy utilizando python 3.4, ya trate de reinstalar pandas pero me dice que esta todo actualizado

Comment: Si te sirve el dato, estoy usando: `pandas==0.20.2`y Python 3.4.0

Comment: segun el sistema yo tengo la 0.19.2, como puedo actualizar a la más reciente?

Comment: Alejandro acabo de ver el comentario en mi respuesta a tu anterior pregunta. Te respondo aquí, el problema es que como crees tu versión de Pandas no dispone del método implementado. Los pasos para actualizar son algo genéricos y pueden variar en función del sistema operativo en el que trabajes, cualquier problema comenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método  `pandas.api.types.infer_dtype`  está disponible a partir de la versión 0.21.0 de Pandas y a su vez se marcó como ***"Deprecated"*** el método que sustituye, `pd.lib.infer_dtype`. Actualmente, en Pandas 0.22.0, sigue disponible esta última, lanzándose un warning si se usa, dado que en futuras versiones va a desaparecer por lo que el código deberá ser actualizado.

Como has intuido, dado que usas la versión 0.19.2, no existe este método en tu instalación de Pandas.

En mi opinión consideraría actualizar tanto Python a la 3.6 (hay mejoras considerables, entre ellas los diccionarios) como Pandas. Esto implicaría instalar todos los paquetes que necesites de nuevo. Si actualizar Python te trae muchos inconvenientes o no es posible por compatibilidades puedes actualizar Pandas a versiones más recientes sin problemas, si no tienes tu versión 3.4 de Python actualizada considera actualizarla también (la última es la 3.4.7 y no requiere de una instalación en limpio como si actualizas a 3.6).

Pandas 0.22 oficialmente está disponible para Python 2.7, 3.5, y 3.6. Para Python 3.4 la última versión oficialmente soportada es la 0.21.1 si no me equivoco:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.21.0/

Para actualizar con `pip` primero **actualiza `pip`** si no lo tienes actualizado:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

después actualiza la el paquete, puedes indicar la versión a usar si lo deseas:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pandas==0.21.1
```

Comment: gracias. ya actualice a la version de python 3.6 mas reciente.

Comment: es posible que me ayudes a revisar un código que tengo en Github, es relacionado al mismo tema. si es posible me puedes decir como te hago llegar el link?.  Espero no faltar a ninguna regla de StackOverflow